# Search for specific word using Go

Tags: go, split

I am new to Go, and am trying to set up a program that splits a Reader object word by word, then records the amount of times the word was found. Here is what I have so far.

```
func Occurrences(word string, s io.Reader) (uint, error) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))

    // Split the reader into words
    var word_count int // Number of the specific word found
    scanner.Split(budfio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {

    }
}
```

I am not sure where to go from there. I do not know what to compare the word I am searching for with. Any help is appreciated

Comment: unsigned values should be reserved for bitwise operations. There's no reason for `uint` here.

Comment: That's an odd comment.  You can use bitwise ops for both int and uint (though I agree it's much less hassle with uint).  You can also count twice as high with a uint than an int, and that works here in situations where you never get negative word counts.

Comment: @dragonx: it's generally accepted best practice to avoid unsigned values for any values used with arithmetic operations. You might not expect a negative count, but you're not going to easily catch that bug when it does happen with an unsigned value. You'll notice Go uses signed values for all counts and indexing operations. "Count twice as high" isn't really a good argument either, that's only 1 bit difference, and you'll have a very special case if you specifically need integer values between (2<<63, 2<<64) -- most likely you'll be looking for arbitrary precision integers at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the word string with the current string token in the scanner

```
func Occurrences(word string, r io.Reader) (int, error) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)

    wordCount := 0
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if scanner.Text() == word {
            wordCount++
        }
    }
    return wordCount, scanner.Err()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gfl1jjM9Bd

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to use a `map[string]int`, where the key is the word, and the value is the count for that word.

You would have to add each word to the map the first time it appears, and increment the count every time after that.